# Reading SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS fields on a Windows socket (for keepalive idle and interval times)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

Given a Windows socket, I want to determine which values it is using for the TCP keepalive idle time and the TCP keepalive interval time (roughly equivalent to the `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` settings on Berkeley sockets).

I see that you can set these values using a `WSAIoctl` call (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ).  However, there does not appear to be any API for reading their current values.  I tried calling `WSAIoctl` with a populated output parameter but `NULL` input parameter, like this:

```
DWORD bytes_returned;
struct tcp_keepalive keepalive_opts;
int rv = WSAIoctl(socket, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, NULL, 0, &keepalive_opts, sizeof(keepalive_opts), &bytes_returned, NULL, NULL);
```

But this returns me a `WSAEFAULT` ("The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.").

I could call `WSAIoctl` with both an input and an output parameter, but I don't want to set the values, I just want to read them.  And as far as I can tell, providing any non-`NULL` input parameter would cause the parameters to be set to whatever values happen to be in that memory space (defined by the `struct tcp_keepalive`; again see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ).

The above also highlights another problem with not knowing what the current values are: I can't set just one of the keepalive idle time or the keepalive interval time - I must blow away both (unknown) values at the same time since they're both members of the struct I'm required to provide.

I know that I could assume things about what values are set based on Windows documentation, but I'd rather not assume.  I see that http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726981.aspx#EDAA defines `KeepAliveInterval` and `KeepAliveTime` default values.  However, the Parameters folder in my Windows 7 registry does not contain either of those keys, so I really have to rely on the documentation being 100% correct here (to know the default values a socket will receive), which is much worse than programmatically retrieving them (even retrieving them from the registry might be ok, but the above experience shows I can't).

Is there any way to get the current TCP keepalive idle time and the TCP keepalive interval time values for a Windows socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `TCP_KEEPIDLE` and `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, which can be used with `getsockopt()`, there is no way to read the current `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` values for a socket, only to set them.

Comment: Is that from your experience?  Did you find this out from some definitive source?  I'm just curious how you know this is the case.

Comment: Err, the documentation? [getsockopt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); [setsockopt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); [WSAIoctl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Well Remy said "there is no way to read the current SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS values for a socket", which is pretty decisive.  It's easy to find documents that say something is possible, but it's hard to prove something is impossible.  Have you reviewed all the relevant documents and determined it's impossible (the ones you list are not exhaustive)?  Or found some other source that says it is?

Comment: There is some conflicting info on this. [This site](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedsocketoptionioctl7b.html) claims you can query the current values by passing a `tcp_keepalive` as the *output* buffer for `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS`, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220.aspx) says that `SIO__KEEPALIVE_VALS` ignores the output buffer. I tried it, the output `tcp_keepalive` is not updated after making multiple `SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` calls, and the `lpcbBytesReturned` parameter always returns 0.